# Is it possible to use an array element as a class instance name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, discord.js

I needed to use an array element as a class instance so multiple users could create a "person." Is is possible to do so and if the answer is yes, how would and where would implement this fix?

This is for a Discord bot with discord.js but I ran into a problem while attempting to make a feature to test my abilities. This feature's purpose was to create a person, name said person, and change its name. I have been able to successfully create a class using "userPerson" as the name however this breaks after trying to change the name. I've tried using the message author id but I could not make it return a Snowflake.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '$'

class person
{
    constructor(name, uid)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = uid;
    }
}

bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Success.');
});

bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot)
        return;

    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0)
        return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "newperson") {
        let args[0] = new person(args[0], message.author.id);
        message.reply("Your new person's name is " + /*class instance.name*/ + ".");
    }
});
```

The program refuses to open and when I use "userPerson" as the class instance, it runs, however running other commands referring to the object causes it to crash, instead of displaying the message reply. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about discord.js but to me it looks like replace /*class instance.name*/ with args[0].name

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but the /*class instance.name*/ is supposed to be a placeholder for the actual name. I'm more specifically concerned about `let args[0] = new person...`

Comment: Your code seems right, why don't you replace that comment with `args[0].name`? Also, what is the error that makes the bot crash?

Comment: The problem is that JavaScript treats `name` as a method for `args[0].name`. What it boils down to is that I need to get the value of `args[0]` and use the element as the class instance name. And to your other question: it doesn’t give me a specific error, using `args[0]` causes it to immediately quit command prompt when I type the command to start it, and using any name causes it to crash when I try to change a value after instantiating it.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output? What do you want it to print? Also I think `let args[0]` should cause an error since you already have a `const` declared with the same name: `const args = ...`. Try changing the name of `let args[0]` to something else